# Domain model, DAL model, DTO model and MVC model.

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

What is the difference between them. 
my understanding at this point is that DAL models are mapped to the database. DTO model transfers data between DAL and Business layer.

Answer (score 2):

You are mostly right. The important thing here is that they are just logical terms, depending on the implementation you could use the same model everywhere. 
Quite a broad question that I am going to cover in short

**DAL model -** usually is the one your DAL talk about, the way it have of representing the entities of your data layer, is usually separated from the rest so it allows you to give it some properties, like Lazy loading (don't get from the database certain heavy properties unless they are asked)

**Domain Model -** this is usually a broader term not related to entities like the previous, but to the whole picture of the problem that piece of software comprehend. Entieties, constraintes, busines rules...

**DTO -** usually are light objects used to transfer between tiers/layers, usually when you expect to go through the wire or cross other boundaries so you try to minimize the information being send across.

**M in MVC -** that is not an entity like DAL models or DTOs but the Business Logic behind your views and controllers.